# compare date with datetime in FilterExpression

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datetime, filter

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date_tb" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [table_1] WHERE [type]='AAA'" FilterExpression="[ScheduledDateTime] = #{0}#">

<asp:ControlParameter Name="ScheduledDateTime" ControlID="date_tb" PropertyName="Text" type="DateTime"/>
```

`ScheduledDateTime` column is of `datetime` type.

`date_tb` textbox only has date.

How do I compared the two of them?

Please note that `CAST()` does not work in `FilterExpression`

and `CONVERT()` in sql server is different from `CONVERT()` in `FilterExpression`.

I tried using `FilterExpression="[ScheduledDateTime] <= #{0}# AND [ScheduledDateTime] >= #{0}#""` but it did not return any result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try
`FilterExpression="[ScheduledDateTime] <= #{0}# AND [ScheduledDateTime] >= #{0}+1#""`
The results are not returned because of time part in **datetime**